# Raspberry & DNSMasq

Tags: raspbian, dns

I am trying to install and configure DNSMasq on my Raspberry.
When I try to edit the configuration using `sudo nano /etc/dnqmasq.conf` I noticed that the file is empty.
Is my DNSMasq corrupted? I noticed other confs that this files is not empty.

Comment: How did you install DNSMasq? DId you use `apt-get`? Also, I see you typed `dnQmasq.conf`. Is that the correct file name? What's supposed to be in that file?

Comment: OK I am officialy idiot! It was a typo :P

Comment: So.... problem fixed?

Comment: I will check and let you know in a while since I did this more than 3 times so I believe that the previous tries I was editing the correct file. Let you know in a while

Comment: all right. Good Luck!